# How to use timers in React hook?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I developing an App with react-native and I'm trying to set an animation for its splash screen. I want to navigate to the next screen after 3 secs. I want to know how I can use timers (like setTimeOut()) with react hooks like useEffect(). this is my code:

```
const SplashScreen = props => {
    const opacityVal = new Animated.Value(0);
    const fadeAnime = () => {
        Animated.timing(opacityVal, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 2000,
            useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start()
    }
    let timer = setTimeout(() => props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'UserAuthenication'}), 2000);

    useEffect(fadeAnime, [opacityVal]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        return(() => clearTimeout(timer))
    }, []);
    return(
        <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
           <Animated.View style={{opacity: opacityVal}}>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.AnimeContainer}>
                 <Image source={require('../Pics/SplashScreenPic.jpg')} style={styles.ImageContainer}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
           </Animated.View>
        </View>

    );
};
```

I tried to do the work like this as it is obvious in the code but it didn't work:

```
let timer = setTimeout(() => props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'UserAuthenication'}), 2000);
 useEffect(()=>{
        return(() => clearTimeout(timer))
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the timer inside the `useEffect` call:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setTimeout(() => props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'UserAuthenication'}), 2000);
  return(
    () => clearTimeout(timer)
  )
}, [props.navigation]);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate, what happened? What do you mean it didn't work?

Comment: After the animation finished, the app was supposed to navigate to the next screen. but it didn't happen.